# CAS with Glassfish Cluster and load blancer

Tags: java, glassfish, cluster-computing, cas

I'm trying to implement a CAS authentication system in a clustered environment, the problem is that after the user authenticates the load balancer routes the CAS tickets to the wrong instance of the cluster, resulting in a TickedValidationException.

Does anyone know how to make it work properly?
I've been searching for it for days, and I can't find to much about it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making use of sticky sessions on the load balancer. If you are using Apache HTTPD, you may find this useful [mod_proxy_balancer](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html), specially the examples section.